# Checking multiple columns for a concatenated match MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, concatenation

Hi i've hit a problem with my SQL queries, i have a table that contains 3 columns, one for vehicle **brands**, one for **models** and one for **model versions**.

So my data is split like

```
BRAND   || MODEL || MODEL VERSION
RENAULT || R4    || R4 1.1 GTL
```

I've been asked to replace our current dropdown system with an input to make it easier for users to select their vehicle.

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete and my query looks something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (brand, ' ', model, ' ', version) as data from vehicles WHERE brand LIKE '%Golf%' OR model LIKE '%Golf%' OR version LIKE '%Golf%' LIMIT 5
```

So far so good, this will output "RENAULT R4 R4 1.1 GTL" if i type in "RENAULT"... the problem here comes when the user inserts something like *Renault R4* instead of just "Renault"

As they've included the **Model** name as well as the **Brand** then it doesn't really match any of my columns in the Database and my Ajax call returns no results.
I need to query the actual result set from that concat instead so that anything the users type in will match the results, but i have no idea how i can do this.

In desperation i tried to type `where data LIKE '%RENAULT R4%'` but as expected this also doesn't work... What can i do in this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and slow way: Split the string by spaces and ask for each word.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
  (brand LIKE '%Renault%' OR model LIKE '%Renault%' OR version LIKE '%Renault%')
  AND (brand LIKE '%R4%' OR model LIKE '%R4%' OR version LIKE '%R4%')
LIMIT 5
```

Keep in mind, that query like this one does not allow use of any index, so it is very slow.

The more complicated, but much faster implementation is to use [fulltext index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html). You need recent version of MySQL (5.6 or newer); older versions support fulltext only on MyISAM tables which are not really a database.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON vehicles(brand, model, version);
SELECT ... FROM vehicles
WHERE MATCH(brand, model, version) AGAINST('Renault R4')
LIMIT 5;
```

(Query not tested, but you should get the idea.)

Comment: @Josef_Kufner The fulltext index is returning everything, if i match against Renault R4 it returns all instances of Renault, not just the ones that match that string... :(

Comment: The match-against operator returns score of how relevant the row is to the query. You can sort rows by the score and offer best matches first. Also, there are more options how to use fulltext - take a look into documentation and play with them a little.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this one, but I believe there are better ways to do it.

```
OR CONCAT (brand, ' ', model, ' ', version) LIKE '%RENAULT R4%'
```